# Why does NSArray didn't call copyWithZone: method?

Tags: ios

As we know,when we call an instance's copy method, system will call it's copyWithZone: method. But when I override NSArray's copyWithZone: method through category with a breakpoint in it，then sent copy method to an instance of NSArray，I found that system doesn't call that copyWithZone: method.Why?

Comment: Please show your category implementation and use.